# How to compare two one hot encoded lists?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, keras, one-hot-encoding

I'm training a CNN on a large dataset of images with two classes, and I've done one hot encoding to my validation classes (y_test):

```
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=2)
```

I want to compare these with the predictions my classifier makes, which I've also one hot encoded like:

```
y_pred = model.predict_classes(x_test)
y_pred = to_categorical(y_pred, num_classes=2)
```

What I want to accomplish with this comparison is to find where my classifier has made a mistake, and to save the image that's been classified incorrectly in a new folder. But I don't think I'm doing the comparison right at all:

```
for i in range(0, len(y_test)):
if y_pred[i].any() != y_test[i].any():
    image = x_test_copy[i]
    path = 'path'
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , str(i)+'.jpg'), image)
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: maybe try `(y_pred[i] != y_test[i]).any()`?

Comment: Are you using Keras `to_categorical`?

Comment: @rayryeng yes, I am using Keras

Comment: @saremisona OK. Thanks.  I've retagged your question for completeness.  BTW, I'm not sure why you want to compare the one-hot encoding vectors when you can just compare the actual labels themselves.  It's simpler because you're only compare one integer rather than an array of integers due to the one-hot encoding.

Comment: Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: That's really kind of you, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the Keras [`to_categorical`](https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical) method which computes a one-hot encoding matrix such that each row is the one-hot encoded label of a training sample.  In that case, your comparison is not correct.  You need to first find where the elements are not equal, then impose that if any of them are not correct, you write out the image to file.

Therefore, first find all positions where the one-hot encoding vector do not correspond to each other: `y_pred[i] != y_test[i]` and only then do you impose the `any` method on it that checks for any elements that aren't equal `(y_pred[i] != y_test[i]).any()`.  This means your `if` statement needs to change:

```
for i in range(0, len(y_test)):
    if (y_pred[i] != y_test[i]).any(): # Change
        image = x_test_copy[i]
        path = 'path'
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , str(i)+'.jpg'), image)
```

Answer (score -1):

just multiply the arrays with each other and sum the result to find the total number of correct predictions.

```
(predictions*test_labels).sum()
```